# Static site generation with Nuxt.JS using relative paths

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, vite

I'm using `Nuxt 2.15.8` to generate static pages (migrating to Nuxt 3 is also an option for me if it solves the problem).

It works great when deployed in the root folder of the server but I need it to be served in a subdirectory, like:

https://my.domain.com/folder/subfolder

The problem is that the compiled HTML includes `nuxt` related assets like:

`/_nuxt/123456789.js`

which translates to:

https://my.domain.com/_nuxt/123456789.js which obviously fails as the file is in a subfolder, not in the root.

I tried using `publicPath` config and absolute paths but it is not an option for me as I have several environments with different URLs.

I need to generate static HTML files with relative paths in order to make sure my site works as expected in all the environments, agnostically from the server URL.

I was able to achieve it using `Vite + Vue 3` but migrating to a new implementation is not an option, I need to achieve it using the current `Nuxt` implementation.

I tried using `nuxt-vite` https://vite.nuxtjs.org/ but was not able to achieve relative paths, I still get
`/_nuxt/123456789.js`
instead of

`./_nuxt/123456789.js`

`../_nuxt/123456789.js`

`../../_nuxt/123456789.js`
, etc

Comment: change router base https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#base

Comment: I think router base is not an option as setting `router.base` as `/app/` generates `<script src="/app/_nuxt/fe2321b.js" defer>` on all the levels. The paths are not relative.

Comment: Have you had a chance to resolve your problem? For me it's so important that I start to think to get rid of both Nuxt and Nuxt Content since both things doing plenty of things I just don't need (as ssr) still failing such a simple thing as configuring relative path for files.

Comment: @ArseniiFomin you'll be plenty lucky if OP answers back here. Mainly because the post is also 1yo+ old. Post it on some community (Nuxt's discord) or create a new question with the latest Nuxt3 version (and Vite).

Comment: @kissu Thank you for the suggestion. I've decided that I'm fed up with Nuxt, currently trying to migrate my project to pure Vite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    baseURL: '/mydir',
    buildAssetsDir: '/mydir/_nuxt/',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not supported in plain nuxt 2 but if you use `nuxt-vite` you can set vite.base to `''` or `'./'` in `nuxt.config` to make the paths relative.

Comment: I don't understand why, but Vite just ignores "base" config (Nuxt 3 with Vite enabled by default):   "vite: {
    base: '/my_real_app_location'' // or just './' as said in their docs
  }," is ignored and all paths in index.html are still "/_nuxt/" ones..

Answer (score -3):

Or just edit index.html manually...

Comment: Not sure that doing this kind of operation on each build is a reliable and lont-term solution.